# Inserting / Updating battery info into db on action_power_connected / disconnected

Tags: android, database, service, broadcastreceiver

I am a newbie to Android Dev as such, but have lately started with creating a BroadcastReceiver-Service based app which listens for ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED & ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED broadcasts. My service gets invoked fine on receipt of both these actions, but I am facing 2 issues (or concerns),

1) Because, I need to insert battery info into db upon receiving ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, I start the service and let it do the insert part. Now after the data insertion is complete, how do I stop the service ? I read about stopSelf etc. Is there a bettery way to do it?

2) Upon receiving the ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED, I again need to either start the service (if not already running) and then update the 1st entry with charging disconnection info and then again stop the service finally. In this case, how do I tell the service, that it needs to call the update method, because a DISCONNECT intent is received.

Please guide.
If someone requires, code segments to understand, I can post that as well, but let me know, if thats required.

Thanks and best regards
Omkar Ghaisas